# No categories or products with magento polaroid theme

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to setup the magento with polaroid theme, I followed all the instruction give in README of polaroid theme.

But neither I can see the products nor the categories in the theme.

Here is the instruction I followed - http://ecommerce-themes.com/support/instructions

followed the steps but the featured products/best sellers section refused to come out. can anyone enlightened me?

I think the problem lies in here..

```
read me:
———————————————————–
     To install the modules,
     copy VisualFrames folder and paste to app\code\local\
     copy VisualFrames_FeaturedProducts.xml and paste to app\etc\modules\
copy VisualFrames_NewProducts.xml and paste to app\etc\modules\
copy VisualFrames_Bestsellers.xml and paste to app\etc\modules\
copy VisualFrames_MultiShipping.xml and paste to app\etc\modules\
—————-
FOR THE FEATURED PRODUCT MODULE:
Create a new attribute by going to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Add New Attribute.
Save the new attribute and go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes Sets to add the attribute to the default feature set.
```

any clues, whats going wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use another theme see if its work, if you are facing the same problem I suggest if you reinstall the magento again, although I believe that there are other platform for commerce are way better than magenta for example open cart and presetashop.